# handle live data from RESTful API

Tags: node.js, rest

I am trying to call an RESTful API to get the necessary data using node.js.  They said that they update the data as it changes automatically, but how can they continuously update the data when it is just being called through a GET request?  Also how would I receive the data using node.js for this.

Comment: What api are you trying to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to get realtime updates would be if this restful service supported using websockets (maintain a constant connection to the service) or webhooks (tell the service to send a http request to a url of your choice). What they probably meant is that the data on the server end is availible immediately and you need to fetch data at an interval to keep up to date.

Comment: That is what I thought, but wanted to make sure.  They do support IP/Socket for delivery, so they must have meant using a websocket instead of the RESTful API